# Hide component under a ScrollView when keyboard is open on Android in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

My layout is a ScrollView above a footer. When the keyboard isnt open I need the footer to always be visible on the screen:

https://snack.expo.io/@jamesweblondon/privileged-cashew1

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} value={"Text Input"} />
      </ScrollView>

      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Text>Footer</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
    padding: 50,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    padding: 50,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    padding: 50,
  },
});
```

This works great on iOS. When the keyboard opens you no longer see the footer:
[image]

However on Android the footer moves above the keyboard:

[image]

Can I stop this behaviour? Ive tried using Keyboard events however `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` arn't supported on Android. If I use `keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardDidHide` then the delay means the footer is visible as the keyboard animates up and then disappears, which feels jerky and unpleasant.

```
export default function App() {
  const [keyboardIsOpen, setKeyboardIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
  Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () => {
    setKeyboardIsOpen(true);
  });
  Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () => {
    setKeyboardIsOpen(false);
  });
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} value={"Text Input"} />
      </ScrollView>

      {!keyboardIsOpen && (
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <Text>Footer</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I also couldn't get it working with the `KeyboardAvoidingView`. I'm using Expo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**android:windowSoftInputMode** already available in **[EXPO](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/0b4b044170b90b71074c7e0f52c4f41da020d8db/exponent-view-template/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)**

here is demo: https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/01d462

you should give full **height** to container instead of flex:1

**Code:**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";

const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} value={"Text Input"} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>

      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Text>Footer</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: height
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: "tomato",
    padding: 50,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    padding: 50,
  },
  footer: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    padding: 50
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: This does work. It's a shame that you have to set the height manually. I'm sharing components with React Native Web, so using JavaScript for layout isn't great.

Comment: @Evanss sorry, I made a solution for android because you mentioned android in question

Comment: It's my fault, I didn't tell you the full requirements. Im sharing this code with Android and iOS, and also the web with React Native Web (within Expo). On the web it's better if you can not use JavaScript for layouts but maybe in this case it's necessary. I'll accept your answer if JavaScript is requited, however an even better solution would be to not use JavaScript. Thanks

Comment: @Evanss yes, you are right we should not use JS for Layout but in our case javascript is required here because flex:1 is using display: "flex" on the web which means footer will not be hidden and keyboard only appear on devices not on web browser and we can also make the separate solution for the web by using platform API from react-native

Comment: The same issue happens on Safari on my iPhone, so maybe this web layout does require JavaScript. This is a shame but for my case the UX is more important.

Comment: Sorry actually the issue is not with Safari. It's with Chrome on Android, but not with Chrome on iOS.

Comment: there is no problem on my safari iPhone and I have tested on chrome on android it is also working good on android https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZYvveJgdq_bsy1WQN6YA5FYNQYhqvu_6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Evanss can you send me the video of chrome android so I can fix solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215657/discussion-between-evanss-and-muhammad-numan).

Comment: @Evanss I have left message in chat. I did not get notification of your message

Answer (score 4):

I found this ready `npm` package. You can install and use it.

Installation from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hide-with-keyboard

You just need to cover the component you want to hide, with `<HideWithKeyboard>`, for example,

```
<HideWithKeyboard>
    <Footer>
    <FooterTab>
    ...More Content Here...
    </FooterTab>
    </Footer>
</HideWithKeyboard>
```

Comment: This package doesn't seem to work any more

Comment: THANK YOU. I have tried everything. All the Keyboard avoiding/aware packages...this is the only thing that actually works for me (working with Expo Go). And it does exactly the logical thing...thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To handle this at the code level you can set the footer display property to `absolute` and `bottom:0`.

If you want to keep the footer at the bottom specially for the android you can set `windowSoftInputMode` in the manifest file. Inside the `<application>` and under `<activity>` block add the following property.

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

then rebuild the app for android, if that still does not work you can also set that to

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: Position absolute doenst do it im afraid.

Im using Expo so I think android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" is already set: https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-set-android-windowsoftinputmode-adjustresize-in-android-manifest-file/587

Answer (score 0):

It works for me of React-Native version: 0.61.2

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```